# When to use EF navigation properties over manual indexed queries?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm wondering if there's any time when performing a query like this:

```
var documentId = report.DocumentId;
return db.Documents.Find(documentId);
```

Would be better or worse than setting up a virtual/nav property and doing this:

```
return report.Document
```

Where DocumentId is the PK on that table.

Are they the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say if it's the document related to the report that you're after then there's no reason not to do `report.Document`. Both your options should perform the same query. What you could do which may provide some benefit is to use `Include`:

```
db.Reports.Include(x => x.Document).First(report => report.Id == id)
```

This would allow you to retrieve the report and its related document in a single query. i.e. the document wouldn't be lazy loaded whenever your code reached `report.Document`.